# Consulta SQL que genere filas dependiendo de cantidad

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla productos en MySQL, que guarda el código de barras y la cantidad de Stock de un producto.

Lo que necesito es generar una consulta SQL de manera a que se puedan repetir las filas con cierta información de un sólo producto dependiendo de la cantidad que tenga en Stock.

Serían tipo filas ficticias. Por ejemplo, si yo tengo 35 productos en stock, la consulta me debería devolver 35 veces el código de barra del producto como resultado.

La tabla productos tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
id_prod    codbar_prod        des_prod     pre_com     stock_act
  1       27478255368371    ASDFADSFADFS    50000         10
  2       27478255368372    ASDESCRIPCION   150000        116
```

Si por ejemplo necesito saber el código de barra del producto 1. Realizaría una consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT codbar_prod FROM productos WHERE id_prod=1;
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
codbar_prod
--------------
27478255368371
```

De esta manera funciona, pero lo que necesitaria es que dicho resultado de consulta se repita teniendo en cuenta la cantidad en stock en este caso; sería por ejemplo un resultado similar al siguiente:

```
codbar_prod
--------------
27478255368371
27478255368371
27478255368371
27478255368371
27478255368371
27478255368371
27478255368371
27478255368371
27478255368371
27478255368371
```

Comment: Y qué has intentado ?  Ese tipo de consultas normalmente tienen un GROUP BY  ....

Comment: No entiendo lo que pides. ¿Puedes incluir ejemplos concretos de lo que buscas?

Comment: transcribe tu tabla a texto

Comment: La verdad que no pude hacer nada aún porque escapa de mis conocimientos, serían tipo filas ficticias, por ejemplo si yo tengo 35 productos en stock.. La consulta me debería devolver 35 veces el código de barra del producto como resultado

Comment: Pon una tabla (no una imagen) que resuma como tienes ahora la información (obvia los campos que no son necesarios para resolver tu pregunta) y muéstranos cual sería el formato resultado esperado

Comment: Lo normal sería que lo duplicaras desde la aplicación que estes realizando, y no directamente desde la consulta

Comment: No es duplicar, el valor es dinámico dependiendo de la cantidad que hay en stock...

Comment: @Angel Pero simpre sera mejor, mucho mejor, que tu consulta regrese `| 27478255368371 | 10 | ` en lugar de tener los id repetidos, no se me ocurre un escenario en que no sea asi

Comment: Lo necesitaba para algo específico, que me retorne de forma repetida los id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cnbandicoot tiene razon, lo duplicas en tu aplicación, en caso de que no quieras hacerlo así, lo que debes es generar vistas solo con números, de la siguiente forma

```
-- Generas 16
CREATE VIEW generator_16
AS SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
   SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
   SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL
   SELECT 12  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 15;
-- Generas 256
CREATE VIEW generator_256
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n * 16 ) + lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_16 lo, generator_16 hi;
-- Generas 4096
CREATE VIEW generator_4k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n * 256 ) + lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo, generator_16 hi;
-- Generas 65536
CREATE VIEW generator_64k
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n * 256 ) + lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_256 lo, generator_256 hi;
-- Generas 1048576
CREATE VIEW generator_1m
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n * 65536 ) + lo.n ) AS n
     FROM generator_64k lo, generator_16 hi;
```

Obtenido de la siguiente liga https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423767/sql-repeat-a-result-row-multiple-times-and-number-the-rows/10432083#10432083

Al realizar tu consulta

```
SELECT codbar_prod
FROM productos p
INNER JOIN generator_64k g ON g.n BETWEEN 1 AND p.stock_act
WHERE id_prod=1
```